# Why does $(-1) \times (-1)$ give +1?

Tags: products

Why is $(-1) \times  (-1)=+1$ ?  What is the intuitive concept ?
 My second question :

How can I show that no triangular number can be of the form $3n-1$ ?

Comment: If you are quit a debt you win money. If you do the opposite of going one step backwards then you go one step forward. Also, it is the only possibility in a ring once you admit the distributive law.

Comment: Try to avoid posing unrelated questions as a single question.

Answer (score 3):

First, let's establish a pattern that can be used to intuitively understand why $1 \times (-1) = (-1)$

$1 \times 3 = 3$

$1 \times 2 = 2$

$1 \times 1 = 1$

$1 \times 0 = 0$

Every time the factor goes down by one, the product goes down by 1 (which is the first factor here).

Extending the pattern:

$1 \times (-1) = -1$

$1 \times (-2) = -2$

and so on.  So $a \times (-b) = - (a \times b)$

Well, we can apply the pattern to the other factor as well:

$(-1) \times 3 = -3$

$(-1) \times 2 = -2$

$(-1) \times 1 = -1$

$(-1) \times 0 = 0$

Every time the factor goes down by one, the product goes down by -1 (which is the first factor here), or in other words, goes up by 1.

Extending the pattern:

$(-1) \times (-1) = 1$

$(-1) \times (-2) = 2$

and so on.  So $(-a) \times (-b) = a \times b$

Now for the second question:

A [triangular number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) is of the form $n(n + 1)/2$.  And of the form $3n - 1$ really means $-1 \pmod 3 \equiv 2 \pmod 3$.

If $n \equiv 0 \pmod 3$, $n(n + 1)/2 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$.

If $n \equiv 1 \pmod 3$, $n(n + 1)/2 \equiv 2/2 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$.

If $n \equiv 2 \pmod 3$, $n(n + 1)/2 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$.

None are equivalent to $2 \pmod 3$, so it can't be expressed as $3n - 1$.

Answer (score 2):

[Multiplying Negatives](http://www.mathsisfun.com/multiplying-negatives.html) has a nice answer involving a number line that may be useful.

> So, by walking backwards, while facing in the negative direction, he
>   moves in the positive direction.

As for triangular numbers, notice that you have to show they can't be congruent to 2 mod 3.  Looking at the formula for these numbers from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number), the formula is $ \frac {n(n+1)}{2}$ which if you look at various values of n mod 3, you could compute the formula based on n which if you think of the products of consecutive numbers mod 3, you should see the answer I'd think.

Answer (score 0):

One way to think of multiplying by $-1$ is as a geometric operation of rotating by 180°. Note that this is exactly what happens on the real line, where a rotation by 180° just flips the sides.

In that case, what would it mean to rotate by 180° two times? It would be the same as rotating by 360°, which is the same as doing nothing. But this is the same as multiplying by 1.

Comment: A picture would go a long way to make your answer even better.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of ways to look at it intuitively:

---

**Positive and negative represent opposite directions:**

When multiplying some value by a positive operand, we retain the direction of that value.

When multiplying some value by a negative operand, we invert the direction of that value.

---

**Positive and negative represent the angles $0$ and $180$:**

When multiplying two operands, we multiply their absolute values and add up their angles.

Answer (score -1):

$$(-1) \times (2) = -2$$
$$(-1) \times (1) = -1$$
$$(-1) \times (0) = 0$$
$$(-1) \times (-1) = \cdots$$

Of course, maybe some of these aren't intuitive either!

Answer (score -1):

For your first question, $(-1)\cdot n$ is the additive inverse of $n$, that is $(-1)\cdot n+n=0$.  What is the additive inverse of $(-1)$?

For the second question, if we had the equality

$$\frac{m(m+1)}{2}=3n-1$$

This would mean that the quantity $m(m+1)$ is congruent to $4$ modulo $6$.  Is that possible?

Answer (score -1):

One somewhat formal way to "see" it is by distributive law: 
$$0=-1\cdot 0=-1\cdot (1+-1)= -1+(-1)\cdot(-1)$$
so $-1+(-1)^2=0$ and $(-1)^2=1$. This may be circular, depending on how you define $-1$, but it might convince you...